# parallel linq permutations

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, compression, permutation

I'd like to use parallel linq to make my where call to GetCompressionRatio faster but all the Plinq statements are of a different syntax and this is the first time I've used linq. I can't handle parallel output but I'd like to fill query as quick as possible.

[Parallel Linq to Object collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745203/parallel-linq-to-object-collection)

```
static double GetCompressionRatio(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    GZipStream gzip2 = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true);

    byte[] raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    gzip2.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
    gzip2.Close();

    byte[] zipped = ms.ToArray(); // as a BLOB
    int startsize = raw.Length;

    double percent = Convert.ToDouble(zipped.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(startsize);
    return percent;
}

var query = 
             from sp1 in polar
                    ...
             from vp15 in polar                           
             where GetCompressionRatio(sp1+...+vp15)>1.5      
             select sp1+...+vp15;


foreach (var element in query)
{
    //output
}
```

Comment: What is `polar`?  Is the question about getting your LINQ query to work or about making it run in parallel? In many cases you can can change a LINQ query to run in parallel simply by calling .AsParallel() (so `polar.AsParallel()`) on the Enumerable with in the query.

Comment: @vossad01 thanks i just found that you can add .AsParallel() on to the end of the from statement for the record string[] polar = new string[6];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added *.AsParallel()* to *polar* and it doubled processor usage

Comment: I cannot tell from you comments so just want to mention out that you will want to add that to the end of every occurrence of polar if you want it to be massively parallel.

Comment: @vossad01 i tried adding it to the end of polar for all instances and it still used the same amount of cpu power

Comment: Just because you specify AsParallel() does not mean that it actually gets executed in parallel, if the libraries think execution time will be faster if the code it not run in parallel (there is overhead from partitioning, context switching, etc.) it will not run it in parallel.